# "Everybody else in our party {has/have} missions of their own."

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns, verb-agreement, objects

Here is my passage:

> Everybody else in our party [has/have] missions of their own.

Now, *Everybody else in our party has a mission of their own* sounds pretty straightforward. But as soon as I make *mission* plural, it doesn't sound right. Yet plurality should reflect *Everybody else*, shouldn't it?

Comment: "plurality should reflect Everybody else, shouldn't it?' Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"has" is correct in both sentences, whether you use "mission" or "missions." The word that defines whether the verb should be single or plural is "everyone," and although "everyone" refers to multiple people, it is a collective noun, meaning it refers to the group as a single unit.

Comment: Nice way to get on the board! I don't know why it looks/sounds funny to me.